# objs in Makefile breaks kernel module

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I'm trying to write a kernel module for a display but I'm struggling with the basics.
If I try to separate source files and define this in Makefile via -objs, the kernel module gets compiled, load, but doesnt do anything.

Code:

driver.c

```
#define LINUX
#include <linux/module.h> 
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include "display.h"

int init_module(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "module registered\n");
    init_display();
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void) {
     printk(KERN_INFO "module unregistered\n");
}
```

display.h

```
#ifndef DISPLAY_H
#define DISPLAY_H
void init_display (void);
#endif
```

display.c

```
#include "display.h"
#include <linux/module.h>  /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>  /* Needed for KERN_ALERT */

void init_display (void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "initialize display\n");
}
```

Makefile

```
obj-m := driver.o
driver-objs := driver.o display.o
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
```

Without the include and driver-objs in Makefile I'm getting the KERN_INFO (load, unload) output, with it, the kernellog is empty.

Any directions, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you really intend to have `driver.o` in both `obj-m` and `driver-objs`? Unless one of those end up in a subdirectory or something, I would think that might cause a problem...

Comment: Also, try the syntax driver-y instead of driver-objs.  That's how it's documented at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt

Comment: Thanks for the input! Sadly neither removing driver.o from driver-objs nor using driver-y (and combined) fixes the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the first rule (obj-m := driver.o) tries to use driver.c directly. When you load your module init_display can't be found and the module loading fails.

Try renaming your driver name so that your Makefile looks like:

```
obj-m := mydriver.o
mydriver-y := driver.o display.o
```

Comment: Thanks!! That was the helping answer! I would love to upvote you, but i'm missing reputation on stackoverflow...

Comment: That's ok Henrik, we're all passing by that phase but please accept it ;-)